# How can I apply manual rule in ctree, partykit package?

Tags: r, party

I'm running decision tree analysis using `ctree()`.
While doing analysis, I feel like adjusting a certain rule manually.
Am I able to do that in `ctree()`?

Answer (score 1):

The `partykit` package has no option to do this easily or out of the box. However, it is possible to piece together a custom tree using the `partykit` infrastructure or to extract the `$node` from a given tree and modify this. See `vignette("partykit", package = "partykit")` and `vignette("constparty", package = "partykit")` for the basic building blocks and for growing a tree from scratch, respectively.